# Difference between du and Finder file sizes

Tags: finder, filesystem, file, sparsebundle, space

I was having a look at the size of libBLAS.dylib at some location in my Mac and du showed it's file size as 572K while the allocated file size (showed by Finder) was 1.4MB. I've read that the lack of sparse files on HFS+ can cause this discrepancy.

My question is that why would a compiled shared library need to be sparse - after all, it's not like anything is going to be modifying it.

Comment: Wonder if it could be that du counts files in 512-byte blocks, while the Finder counts them in 4096-byte blocks due to HFS+?

Comment: Then the difference should be 4K at most, not more than 0.8MB

Comment: Is your question why there is a difference in the reported size, or why this file needs to be a sparse file?

Comment: The former but I'm guessing that's going to involve some explanation of the latter?

Answer (score 1):

Difference is in units they use.

du uses BLOCKSIZE=4096 bytes by default (rounded  if Human Readable format option -h i.e. `df -h`)
Finder uses BLOCKSIZE=1000 by default

```
$du -h /usr/lib/libblas.dylib 
4.0K    /usr/lib/libblas.dylib
```

and same in Finder.

Comment: Can you describe how this explains the "factor 2" difference in size reported by the asker?

Comment: `df -h` and `df -k` gives same results

Comment: I hope they do! But how do you explain the difference to the size reported by Finder?

Comment: I've explained how `Finder` says same as `du`

Comment: @EirNym In the answer (if I understand correctly), you state that using `du -h` should give the same result as the file size in Finder. However, I tried running `du -h` to get the file size of my home folder and it doesn't match the file size Finder reports. (Finder: 122.13G, du:161G)

Comment: @Arc676, have you set BLOCKSIZE? `env BLOCKSIZE=1000 du -h file`