# Why large size calculation difference: Mac Finder vs du?

Tags: macos, finder

I have just noticed that for some of my directories on an external disk there is a huge difference in calculated size depending on whether I use the GUI Finder or `du` (or rather `du -h`). Using Finder on this directory I get 145 GB, whereas `du` gives me 135 GB. That is a difference of 10 GB! Checking another directory I (on my local machine) I get 41 vs 43,7. So there seems to be almost a 10% difference here. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83412/difference-between-du-and-finder-file-sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure but 145GB is [exactly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=145GB+to+GiB) 135 GiB so I think Finder gives result with decimal prefixes while `du` uses the binary ones.
See this [article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/gigabyte-decimal-vs-binary/)

Comment: That must be it -- very informative (and convincing) article reference as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Rnhmjoj This happened to me as well, but I tried googling "122.13 GB in GiB" (my home folder file size according to Finder) and I get 113.742 GiB. However `du` gives me 161G.

Comment: @Arc676 I made a search and `du -kh`should count files by 1024 byte blocks. So what I thought is correct but there must be also something else. I can't figure out.